# Why does MongoDB map-reduce have implicit this

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query

The map-reduce usage is following

```
db.myCollection.mapReduce(function() {
  emit(this.smth);
},
function(key, values) {
  // return something done with key and values
});
```

My question is, why is the map part implemented to have implicit `this` that references the current document being processed? IMO, it would be cleaner to have the current document passed in as an argument to the map function (I prefer to write all my JavaScript without `this`).

In practice this also rules out the use of arrow functions in mongo scripts, since this reference does not work with them.

Comment: Why the downvote? Too broad? Off-topic? Related to some techical details that only developers of Mongo DB will know? Something else? Can the question be improved or should it be removed/closed? I'm asking this as I'm interested in knowing the details behind such as design descision, since IMO implicit `this`is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why is the map part implemented to have implicit `this` that references the current document being processed?

MongoDB's Map/Reduce API was created in 2009, which is well before arrow functions were available in JavaScript (via ES6/ES2015). I can only speculate on the design intention, but much has changed in JavaScript (and MongoDB) since the original Map/Reduce implementation.

The `this` keyword in a JavaScript method refers to the owner or execution context, so setting it to the current document being processed was perhaps a reasonable convention (or convenience) for JavaScript usage at the time. The [`reduce` function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function) has a required prototype of `function (key, values)` so a `map` prototype of `function (doc)` might have been more consistent. However, once an API choice is made, any significant breaking changes become more challenging to introduce.

A more modern take on aggregation might look quite different, and this is the general path that MongoDB has taken. The [Aggregation Framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) introduced in MongoDB 2.2 (August, 2012) is a higher performance approach to data aggregation and should be preferred (where possible) over Map/Reduce.

Successive releases of the MongoDB server have made significant improvements to the features and performance of the Aggregation Framework, while Map/Reduce has not notably evolved. For example, the Aggregation Framework is written in C++ and able to manipulate MongoDB's native [BSON data types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/); Map/Reduce spawns JavaScript threads and has to marshal data between BSON and JavaScript.

> In practice this also rules out the use of arrow functions in mongo scripts, since this reference does not work with them.

Indeed. As at MongoDB 4.0, arrow functions are not supported in Map/Reduce. There is a feature request to support arrow functions which can you watch/upvote in the MongoDB issue tracker: [SERVER-34281](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-34281).

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. So, basically it is a design decision made 10 years ago and was done with the "best intentions", since lots of JS APIs used `this` at the time, and are still forced to use to be backwards-compatible.

Comment: And in general it is JS language feature that prevents using `this` with arrow functions, since it is not bound by default. OTOH, I'm not sure whether an arrow function works with reduce either...